# Страница доступная по IP адресу сервера

Tags: linux, apache, nginx

Есть VPS с установленной на нём Plesk панелью (хотя панель, вероятно, значения не имеет).
На сервере висит несколько сайтов, если перейти не по одному из доменов, а по IP-адресу сервера, то открывается по-умолчанию тот сайт, который был добавлен на сервер последним.

Как установить сайт/страницу открываемую по-умолчанию при переходе напрямую по IP-адресу сервера? Сервер Linux (Apache + Nginx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024917/how-do-you-set-the-default-website-to-serve-when-your-ip-address-is-entered-as-u

Comment: Да, надо бы чаще пытаться гуглить на английском свои вопросы:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем-то ответ в случае с Plesk прост:

1. Необходимо зайти в "Инструменты и настройки" (Tools & Setting)
2. Перейти в "IP-адреса" (вкладка "Инструменты и ресурсы")
3. Открыть нужный IP-адрес
4. Выбрать подписку по-умолчанию.

При попытке изменить конфигурацию Nginx сервер выдаст ошибку (так как в Plesk эта настройка уже существует).

Answer (score 0):

Указываете конфигурацию Nginx по умолчанию для 80 порта:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    root /default/site/path;
    ...
    location site_1 {
        ...
    }
    location site_2 {
        ...
    }
}
```

Если идет проксирование на Apache, то там ничего менять не надо, просто определяем директории на которые идут запросы с Nginx.